# Xamarin.Mac show default filename when using NSSavePanel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

In a Xamarin.Forms application I wish to implement a file Save As operation in the Xamarin.Mac project. When showing the NSSavePanel, I wish to present the current file name as the default.

I have seen setNameFieldStringValue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673386/how-can-i-preset-the-filename-in-nssavepanel) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels.html) but an equivalent method does not appear to be exposed in Xamarin.

Is it possible to do this?

Here's the code I'm working with.

```cs
public string GetSaveAsFilePathOrNull(string defaultFileName)
{
    var dlg = NSSavePanel.SavePanel;
    dlg.SetNameFieldStringValue(defaultFileName); // Compiler error, no such method

    if (dlg.RunModal() == 1)
    {
        var url = dlg.Url;

        if (url != null)
        {
            var path = url.Path;
            return path;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you share some code or something what you've tried so far? that will help to figure out a solution

Comment: @RonaldHaan Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xamarin.Mac C# normalization of the ObjC function `NSSavePanel.SetNameFieldStringValue` is a read/write property (`NSSavePanel.NameFieldStringValue`).

```
var dlg = NSSavePanel.SavePanel;
dlg.NameFieldStringValue = defaultFileName;
```